# Access webservise the same solution but in different project C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**I have the following project in ASP .NET C #**

Solution - *MBS*

Projects

*
APL

BLL

DAL

ECL*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hM0y.png)

Within the Aplication project will store HTML , CSS, JS .

The problem is that I can not access the BLL(WebService) project via URL using AJAX .

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the BLL project as your start-up project in Visual Studio.  Then start debugging and the local URL to access your web service will likely be in address bar of the browser that opens.